# How to best create linked pdf to point data in ArcGIS server 10 sde 9.3?

Tags: arcgis-server, enterprise-geodatabase, attachments

I would like to create point data which offers a link-field to open a pdf file which I will have on my server. I have just read about "attatchments" which are new to ArcGIS 10, but this option isn´t available for my sde9.3 feature classes - only my filegeodatabases in 10.0 Desktop. I have sde 9.3 running with ArcGIS Server 10.0.

How would I best create pdf links to point features classes in SDE?

Comment: Are you aware of [Hyperlinks](http://resources.arcgis.com/en/help/main/10.2/#/Using_Hyperlinks/00s500000004000000/)?

Comment: Your title mentions "ArccGIS server 10 sde 9.3" but the body of your questions only mentions "ArcGIS 10".  I think this may mean that your are using ArcGIS Server 10.0 to access your DBMS via ArcSDE 9.3 but an edit to your question would make that much clearer. http://meta.gis.stackexchange.com/a/3353/115

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should be able to add attachments to feature classes in SDE 10. I have seen it done before.

http://help.arcgis.com/en/arcgisdesktop/10.0/help/index.html#//001t000003vt000000.htm

You will enable attachments, at which point a table is added to the geodatabase along with a relationship class tying the attachment table to your feature class. You insert your pdf link in the attachment table and anytime you select the associated feature, you can see the pdf link in the attribute table.

Comment: I *think* the asker may be using ArcSDE 9.3.

Comment: I was unsure so I provided the documentation should the asker be using 10.

Comment: An upvote for taking the time to do that.